# DataTables:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a php file that creates a table with values from Database.

Here is the HTML printed out:

```
<table id="table" class="display dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headContainer">
            <th colspan="1"> 
                <div id="tablePerPage"></div>
            </th>
            <th colspan="1">
                <div id="tableSearch"></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="rowHeader">
                Locations
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableContent">
        <tr class="tableRow">
            <td> 
                <a href="q=NewYork">New York</a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
      autoWidth: true
      responsive: true,
      lengthChange: true,
      ordering: true
 });

 $('#tableSearch').html($('.dataTables_filter'));
 $('#tablePerPage').html($('#table_length'));
```

The headers are constant , But the body data are changed dynamically.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `<th>` in `".headContainer"` and one `<th>` in the next row, but with `colspan="2"` (equivalent of two `<th>`), and only one `<td>` in the table body, which has caused a "mismatch" of columns and `<td>` data in the table.

If you add another `<td>`:

```
<tbody id="tableContent">
    <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
            <a href="q=NewYork">New York</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="q=Chicago">Chicago</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

DataTables should be happy.